# One liner nokogiri xpath lookup

Tags: xpath, nokogiri

When I look up an xpath with

```
b.xpath("td[@class='team']/img").each do |d|
  puts d['id']
end
```

The element "d" is a html node. I can reference attributes in it.

But when I attempt to look up the same element in one line, it gets returned as a string.

```
c = b.xpath("td[@class='team']/img")[0]
```

There is only one element I in the array, I don't need to loop through anything `.each`. Is there a way to make this one line?

Comment: Have you tried with `at_xpath`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing something like this:

```
t = a.xpath("tr/td[@class='team']/img")
away = t[0]['id']
home = t[1]['id']
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a test I put together:

```
html = '<div id="foo">bar</div>'

b = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(html)

b.xpath(".//div").each do |d|
  puts d.class
  puts d['id']
end

c = b.xpath(".//div")[0]

puts c.class
puts c['id']
```

As you would expect, the resulting output is:

```
Nokogiri::XML::Element
foo
Nokogiri::XML::Element
foo
```

So both approaches are in fact returning an object of type Nokogiri::XML::Element.